# Proving using linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

This is the question :

Prove or disprove :

If $V$ is a linear space and $T: V\to V$ is a linear transformation such that $T^2 = 0$.

(the zero transformation), then $\operatorname{Im}(T) \subseteq \operatorname{Ker}(T)$.

I thought about it a lot and it just seems right but something tells me i'm missing something, and if it's correct, i have no idea how to prove this.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true. If $y\in \operatorname{Im}(T)$, then $y = Tx$ for some $x\in V$. Then $Ty = T(Tx) = T^2(x) = 0$, which implies $y\in \operatorname{Ker}(T)$.

Comment: I'm with you until the ending part, i can't see why it is that easily implies that  y∈Ker(T)

Comment: @AmirH since $Ty = 0$, $y\in \operatorname{Ker}(T)$ by definition of $\operatorname{Ker}(T)$.

Comment: Yep, got it, thank you all so much.